# I am receiving 0 for all my outputs

Tags: java

**Desired Output:**

```
Total: 55.0
Average: 5.5
Minimum Value: 1.0
Maximum Value: 10.0
The data being used is: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
```

**My code is**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CH8_11 {

//Constants Declaration
//*********************

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Variable Declaration Section
    //****************************
    int[] numbers;
    int SIZE;
    int i;
    int max;
    int min;
    int total;
    double average;





    // Variables Initialization Section
    //*********************************
    File file = new File("C:\\testing1.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    SIZE = 0;
    max = 0;
    min = Integer.Max_VALUE;
    i = 0;
    total = 0;
    average = 0.0;



    //Keyboard
    //********



    // Code Section
    //*************
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        SIZE++;
        scanner.next();
    }

    while(scanner.hasNext() && i < numbers.length)
    {
        numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        i++;
    }

    for(int j = 1; j < numbers.length; j++)
    {
        if(numbers[j] > max)
            max = numbers[j];
    }

    for(int j = 1; j < numbers.length; j++)
    {
        if(numbers[j] < min)
            min = numbers[j];
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
    {
        total += numbers[j];
        average = total / (double)numbers.length;
    }





    //Output Section
    //**************
    System.out.println("Numbers being used: "+ java.util.Arrays.toString(numbers));
    System.out.print("---------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("\nMaximum Value: " + max);
    System.out.print("\n-----------------");
    System.out.print("\nMinimum Value: " + min);
    System.out.print("\n-----------------");
    System.out.print("\nAverage: " + average);
    System.out.print("\n-----------------");
    System.out.print("\nTotal: " + total);




    //Resource Cleaning
    //*****************
    scanner.close();




}

}
```

Thanks to the help of the community I have fixed my Minimum value solution. I modified my code to the suggestions of one of the comments below that allows the array to become the size of the file so its not a fixed size. But now I am receiving 0's for all outputs and I cant figure out why.

Comment: ` min = numbers[0];` - what value does `numbers[0]` have when this line executes?

Comment: you can put all your conditionals in one loop. plus calculate the average after the loop not inside it. I'm not sure you're using SIZE anywhere. I'd change the array to a collection like arraylist. the problem you're getting with zeros is that you're not resetting the scanner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not initialize your `min` as

```
min = numbers[0];
```

That puts a `0` there and is bound to be the minimum value given your array values. Initialize it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Or, just use the maximum value available that you calculated just before the loop like

```
for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
{
    if(numbers[j] > max)
        max = numbers[j];
}

min = max;
for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
{
    if(numbers[j] < min)
        min = numbers[j];
}
```

Also notice that you need to start iterating with `int j = 0`. Otherwise, your code is ignoring the first array value in calculating both the maximum and minimum values.

---

To count the number of integers available in the file

```
File file = new File("C:\\testing1.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

SIZE = 0;

// count the numbers
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
  SIZE++;
  scanner.next()
}

numbers = new int[SIZE];

// reopen the scanner
scanner.close();
scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: Do you know how I would make this so I could resize the array at runtime without using ArrayList?

Comment: The thing with Arrays is that they have a fixed size. They can't grow dynamically but you can ask your users to provide an input size, then `int size = scanner.nextInt()` can be used to initialize the array as `new int[size];`

Comment: I see, but, the user isn't supposed to know the size of the array (or how many numbers are in the file)....I used arraylist and a while nested if statement, but my professor said he didn't want that...So now I have this code and I'm lost without ArrayList...Yes this is for a homework assignment..:/

Comment: I don't mean to be pushy, but it gives me a syntax error, asking my to add a semicolon after scanner.next(). If I do this number = new int[SIZE] gets blocked.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. You need a `;` there. Could you explain what you mean by getting blocked?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was Size++ and it was because I had set as final. I fixed it.

Comment: I am recieving an array full of zero's though, is this because I have SIZE = 0 and then I put SIZE int number[]?

Comment: No, that's because when an array is created, it's automatically initialized with its type's default value. Since, this is an `int[]`, it gets initialized with `0`s. This was happening when you had `SIZE = 10` as well. The array gets filled when you iterate over your `scanner` in the loop below (in both the cases).

Comment: So i tried to changefor(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
{
    if(numbers[j] < min)
        min = numbers[j];
}

to

for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
{
    if(numbers[SIZE] < min)
        min = numbers[SIZE];
} 

but, i get an outofbounds exception

Comment: No, that code is fine. You need only `j` there because `j` is the counter that goes from index `0` to `numbers.length - 1`.

Comment: hmm. ok, so basically it reading the file, but its replacing everything in file with 0's. because I'm getting 10 - 0's so I'm sure its read the file, or is it only reading the numbers of integers in the file instead of reading the file?

Comment: Where are you seeing the `0`s? In the file or in the output? Where's your `numbers = new int[SIZE];` code? Why are you not reopening the scanner? I don't see my code snippets in your latest update.

Comment: I had them in my program on my computer, I forgot to add it to the question, I didn't close the scanner after the numbers = new int[SIZE], I just did it. It's all fixed. Thanks for the insight, I'll start to use this for other code I write, its a good example.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `min` with 0. Then you check every value entered whether it is smaller than that. None is, so it stays null.

Initialize `min` with a high value, line `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

UPDATE:

There is another error in your code: you start your for-loops with 1 instead of 0, skipping the first element of your array

Comment: Same thing as Ravi, I receive 2 for minimum value when I do this.

Comment: Thanks! Just like Ravi, you both were, haha!